# Angularjs http post call in iteration and use the response from each call

Tags: angularjs, node.js, for-loop, promise

I have an array and trying to create data in application using http POST call.Each post call will return an id which will be the input to the next call.

Below is the sample Code block.

Objective is to create hierarchy as 'C' is parent of 'B' and so on.As a response I am getting Id and then updating categoryNameIdMap field with the value/Id. But as javascript does not wait for response, I am getting undefined as parentId.

```
$scope.path = ['A','B','C']  
$scope.categoryNameIdMap  = {}; // map of name and id ..ex. "A":1121
angular.forEach($scope.path, function(item) {
// for first value 'A', parent Id is 0
if (item == 'A'){
    data = {
       "name": item,
       "parentId": 0
    }
}
else{ 
// for value 'B', parent id is the id of 'A' which will be generated 
// once we create the category on server and get the response.For C, 
// parent Id will be id of 'B'
    data = {
       "name": item,
       "parentId": $scope.categoryNameIdMap[item]
    }
}
// Here we are creating the category and storing the response in a 
// map of (name,id).

$http.post("createCategories", data).then(function(response) {
    $scope.categoryNameIdMap[item] = response.id;
});
}
```

I have also tried promise but not able to use response before making next POST call.

Note : This is the sample code written for this question.

Comment: Why are you using .success that is deprecated (use .then) and I believe removed from any of the more recent versions of 1.x, this also begs the question which version are you using?  Also not clear what context your triggering this code in, you say the parentId isn't present but you don't show how the categoryNameIdMap[item] is being populated or how this code is triggered.

Comment: So you need the data to get the data? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have added few comments in Question, Please check.

Comment: you `else` code  sets `"parentId": $scope.categoryNameIdMap[item]` ... only after this do you attempt to *asynchronously* get `$scope.categoryNameIdMap[item]` - javascript doesn't retrospectively change `parentId` property for you - but of course, `data.parentId` is used in the request to get the value of `parentId` - so, not really sure how you expect this to work

Answer (score 0):

If I read it right, I think you want to use the response.id of A when making the request for 'B', and B for C

You can use Array#reduce method to chain the promises so that each iteration will wait for the result of the previous `post`

Like this

```
$scope.path = ['A', 'B', 'C']
$scope.categoryNameIdMap = {};
$scope.path.reduce((promise, name) => promise.then(parentId => $http.post("createCategories", {name, parentId})).then(response => $scope.categoryNameIdMap[name] = response.id), Promise.resolve(0));
```

> You'll notice, instead of using `item` as the value for each iteration, I used `name` - this was just so I can use some shorthand ES2015+
>
> so, instead of

```
$http.post("createCategories", {name: item, parentId: parentId})
```

> can use the shorthand

```
$http.post("createCategories", {name, parentId})
```

---

Now, since your question shows no ES2015+, the ES5 version is below with some explanation

```
$scope.path.reduce(function (promise, name) {
    // chaining the promises ensures the requests get done in order
    return promise.then(function (parentId) {
        return $http.post("createCategories", { name: name, parentId: parentId });
    }).then(function (response) {
        // assign the response id to $scope.categoryNameIdMap[name] and return it for the next items parentId
        return $scope.categoryNameIdMap[name] = response.id;
    });
// first parentId is 0, this also serves to "start" the Promise chain
}, Promise.resolve(0));
```